# Export conda yml environment file without package version alphanumeric text

Tags: yaml, virtualenv

As a newbie in python, I have successfully exported my project environment into a yml file so as to share so far. See sample here

name: climate

channels:

- conda-forge
- defaults

dependencies:

- affine=2.3.0=py_0
- bokeh=2.4.2=py310h5588dad_0

However, I wish to have the dependencies without the alphanumeric text following the package versions.
I like to have -bokeh=2.4.2 not bokeh=2.4.2=py310h5588dad_0.

Answer (score 7):

Add the `--no-builds` flag when you're exporting the environment.

```
    conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml
```